# "Unexpected end of JSON input" error when installing angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm-install

I am trying to install angularjs using npm on my computer and get the following errors:

**This is the first error**

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rsion":"0.4.8","depen'
```

**This is the second error**

```
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sanja\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T11_02_18_131Z-debug.log
```

What causes these, and how can I fix them?

Comment: Can you share more info regarding the packages that you try to install?

Comment: angular version 7 and i have installed nodejs version 11 and npm version 6.5.0

Comment: i have discovered the error have to clear / delete the npm-cache folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is follow official guide:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Is will allow you to generate sample with all dependencies you need.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an incorrect/badly formed configuration file.
Can you try checking the package.json at your project root or if it is okay, try re-initializing the app creation ?